# Не могу сохранить изменения в контейнере докера

Tags: python, linux, docker

Я с хоста коппирую файл в докер (docker cp file.txt 4f20e373e04b: / root) захожу в диркторирию докера и там есть этот файл. Но только я перезапускаю докер этот файлик пропадаеа.Запускаю докер командой docker run -p 5000: 5000 lorry- server.Я новичок в докерах , помогите пожалуста)

Answer (score 1):

Данные в контейнере сохраняться, если Вы остановите просто остановите контейнер, а не удалите.

```
# запуск контейнера (без опции --rm)
docker run --name foo ...
# скопировали туда файлик
docker cp ...
# остановили контейнер
docker stop foo
# запустили контейнер, файлик еще там
docker start foo
# остановили и удалили контейнер
docker stop foo && docker rm foo
# файлик утерян навсегда, надо снова делать docker run и docker cp
```

А вообще, чтоб не делать лишних телодвижений рекомендую использовать опцию `-v` в команде `docker run`, тогда Ваш файл будет всегда в контейнере

```
docker run -v /path/to/file.txt:/path/inside/container/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то docker run создаёт новый контейнер из image и в нём нет уже нет этого файла.
Вам нужно добавить этот файл в docker image и тогда он будет при запуске контейнера.